# Can i use dataframe with sparse vector to do cross-validation tuning?

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, pyspark, cross-validation, apache-spark-ml

i'm training my multilayer Perceptron Classifier. Here's my training set.The features are in sparse vector format.

```python
df_train.show(10,False)
+------+---------------------------+
|target|features                   |
+------+---------------------------+
|1.0   |(5,[0,1],[164.0,520.0])    |
|1.0   |[519.0,2723.0,0.0,3.0,4.0] |
|1.0   |(5,[0,1],[2868.0,928.0])   |
|0.0   |(5,[0,1],[57.0,2715.0])    |
|1.0   |[1241.0,2104.0,0.0,0.0,2.0]|
|1.0   |[3365.0,217.0,0.0,0.0,2.0] |
|1.0   |[60.0,1528.0,4.0,8.0,7.0]  |
|1.0   |[396.0,3810.0,0.0,0.0,2.0] |
|1.0   |(5,[0,1],[905.0,2476.0])   |
|1.0   |(5,[0,1],[905.0,1246.0])   |
+------+---------------------------+
```

Fist of all, i want to evaluate my estimator on a hold out method, here's my code:

```python
from pyspark.ml.classification import MultilayerPerceptronClassifier
from pyspark.ml.evaluation import MulticlassClassificationEvaluator

layers = [4, 5, 4, 3]
trainer = MultilayerPerceptronClassifier(maxIter=100, layers=layers, blockSize=128, seed=1234)
param = trainer.setParams(featuresCol = "features",labelCol="target")

train,test = df_train.randomSplit([0.8, 0.2])
model = trainer.fit(train)
result = model.transform(test)
evaluator = MulticlassClassificationEvaluator(
    labelCol="target", predictionCol="prediction", metricName="accuracy")
print("Test set accuracy = " + str(evaluator.evaluate(result)))
```

But it turns out the error:**Failed to execute user defined function($anonfun$1: (vector) => double).** Is this because i have sparse vector in my features?What can i do?

And for the cross-validation part, I coded as following:

```python
X=df_train.select("features").collect()
y=df_train.select("target").collect()
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score,KFold
k_fold = KFold(n_splits=10, random_state=None, shuffle=False)
print(cross_val_score(trainer, X, y, cv=k_fold, n_jobs=1,scoring="accuracy"))
```

And I get: **it does not seem to be a scikit-learn estimator as it does not implement a 'get_params' methods.**
But when i look up the document, i didn't find get_params method.Can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a number of issues with your question...

Focusing on the second part (it is actually a separate question), the error message claim, i.e. that

> it does not seem to be a scikit-learn estimator

is indeed correct, since you are using the `MultilayerPerceptronClassifier` from PySpark ML as `trainer` in the scikit-learn method `cross_val_score` (they are *not* compatible).

Additionally, your 2nd code snippet is not at all PySpark-like, but scikit-learn-like: while you use correctly the input in your 1st snippet (a *single* 2-column dataframe, with the features in one column and the labels/targets in the other), you seem to have forgotten this lesson in your second snippet, where you build separate dataframes `X` and `y` for input to your classifier (which should be the case in scikit-learn but not in PySpark). See the [`CrossValidator` docs](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/api/python/pyspark.ml.html#pyspark.ml.tuning.CrossValidator) for a straightforward example of the correct usage.

From a more general viewpoint: if your data fit in the main memory (i.e. you can `collect` them as you do for your CV), there is **absolutely no reason to bother with Spark ML**, and you would be far better off with scikit-learn.

--

Regarding the 1st part: the data you have shown seem to have only 2 labels `0.0/1.0`; I cannot be sure (since you show only 10 records), but if indeed you have only 2 labels you should not use `MulticlassClassificationEvaluator` but [`BinaryClassificationEvaluator`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/api/python/pyspark.ml.html#pyspark.ml.evaluation.BinaryClassificationEvaluator) - which however, does not have a `metricName="accuracy"` option... [EDIT: against all odds, seems that `MulticlassClassificationEvaluator` indeed can work for binary classification, too, and it is a handy way to get the accuracy, which is not provided with its binary counterpart!]

But this is not why you get this error (which, BTW, has nothing to do with the `evaluator` - you get it with `result.show()` or `result.collect()`); the reason for the error is that the number of nodes in your first layer (`layers[0]`) is 4, while your input vectors are evidently 5-dimensional. From the [docs](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/api/python/pyspark.ml.html#pyspark.ml.classification.MultilayerPerceptronClassifier):

> Number of inputs has to be equal to the size of feature vectors

Changing `layers[0]` to 5 resolves the issue (not shown). Similarly, if you indeed have only 2 classes, you should also change `layers[-1]` to 2 (you'll not get an error if you don't, but it won't make much sense from a classification point of view).

Comment: Thank you so much, it shows that the problems for part1 and part2 are exactly what you mentioned. Now i've solved all of them.Appreciate it.